# Is MySql log maintaining the open connection count details for past?

Tags: mysql

My customer was asking that two days back he was getting exception due to max connection exceed. Is there any way to find out how many connection was open in past in MySQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can view this status:

```
mysql> show global status like 'max_used_connections';
```

This shows you the high-water mark for the most used connections. It is reset if you restart the MySQL Server.

But this doesn't tell you how many connections there were at a certain time in the past. For that you'd need to use some kind of monitoring service like [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html) or [Percona Monitoring and Management](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-monitoring-and-management). A service like that samples a lot of metrics every interval of time and saves them, so you can see trends and history.